# é possivel ver a ordem de execução do entity?

Tags: entity-framework

Então, é possível eu olhar a ordem de execução das `Querys` que o `Entity Framework` monta?

O meu problema, é que ele esta tentando fazer uma deleção na ordem errada, mesmo apos eu fazer as chamadas na ordem que no sql server funciona.

Código:

```
itensPVF.ForEach(e => this.pvfService.RemoverPorChave(e.Chave));                        
RemoverItemSolicitado(chaveOS, numeroItensPvf);
```

No caso, esse `itemPVF` tem que ser apagado primeiro por conta do seu relacionamento com a tabela que é apagada na sequencia, só que na hora do `commit` pelo `entity`, ele não entende dessa forma e estoura o **erro**:

> `{"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint     \"FK_TB_ITEM_OS_PVF_TB_ITEM_SOLICITADO\".
>          The conflict occurred in database \"BANCO\", table \ "dbo.TB_ITEM_OS_PVF\", column 'CD_ITEM_SOLICITADO'.
>        \r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

Comment: Qual é o seu contexto?

Comment: O que é `pvrService`? O que tem no código de `RemoverPorChave`?

Comment: o pvrService é o meu servico referente a regra de negocio, o removerPorChave é um generics que no final vai chamar o .Remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Então, é possível eu olhar a ordem de execução das `Querys` que o `Entity Framework` monta?

Sim é possível, fazer um auditoria das [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) com [Database.Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn479056.aspx):

```
var db = new Contexto();
db.Database.Log = x => System.Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Depois dessas linhas faça o processo que deseja, que ao executar comandos [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) será mostrado um saída na sua tela do console.

<sub>**Observação:** esse exemplo de código é para ser realizado em `Console Application`, mas, nada impede ser utilizado em diversos contextos.</sub>

Tem também uma ferramenta que pode ser utilizada para tal fim a [`SQL Server Profiler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181091.aspx), possui mais recursos e traz muitas informações do que está acontecendo no `SQLServer`. Segundo [MSDN - Site Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181091.aspx), *[SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181091.aspx) é uma interface para criar e gerenciar rastreamentos e analisar e reproduzir resultados de rastreamento*.

***Referencias:***

- [Entity Framework 6 – Gerando Log dos comandos SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn479056.aspx)
- [Database Command Logging](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-logging.aspx)
- [Logging and tracing with Entity Framework 6](https://cmatskas.com/logging-and-tracing-with-entity-framework-6/)
- [Using context.Database.Log in MVC web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299038/using-context-database-log-in-mvc-web-app)
- [EF6 SQL Logging – Part 1: Simple Logging](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/)
- [Logging Database Operations](http://tektutorialshub.com/logging-database-operations-entity-framework/)
- [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181091.aspx)
- [Identificando consultas demoradas com o SQL Server Profiler](https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/identificando-consultas-demoradas-com-o-sql-server-profiler/)

Comment: isso vai ajudar e muito, valeu meu caro.

Comment: Além dessa forma que você mencionou, eu consegui ver o log de execução do entity atravez de uma ferramenta do SQL Server, chamada SQL Server Profile.

Comment: Perfeito @SonDotNet eu mesmo já utilizei é perfeita ... Vou usar seu comentário e editar a resposta para ficar mais completa possivel